# Trouble overloading [] operator

Tags: c++, overloading, cin

So I'm doing a program for vectors/matrixes processing and I can't overload index operator which I have to use (as a public method) to access private data of class. Code:

Header:

```
#ifndef WEKTOR_HH
#define WEKTOR_HH

#include "rozmiar.h"
class Wektor {
  float skladowa[ROZMIAR];

  public:
  float operator[] (int i);

};


std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &Strm, Wektor &Wek);
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &Strm, const Wektor &Wek);

#endif
```

Wektor.cpp:

```
#include "Wektor.hh"
#include <iostream>

float Wektor::operator[] (int i){
if(i<=ROZMIAR) return skladowa[i];
 else return skladowa[ROZMIAR];}


std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &Strm, Wektor &Wek){

  std::cin >> Wek[1] >> Wek[2] >> Wek[3];
  return Strm;}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &Strm, const Wektor &Wek){

  std::cout << Wek[1] << Wek[2] << Wek[3] << std::endl;
  return Strm;}
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Wektor.hh"
#include "Macierz.hh"
#include "UkladRownanLiniowych.hh"



using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Wektor w1;
  cin >> w1;
  cout << endl << " Wczytano: " << endl << endl;
  cout << w1 << endl;
}
```

And I get ton of errors. For example, and also the one that bothers me is:

```
tobi@don-VM:~/PO/uklad$ make
g++ -c -g -Iinc -Wall -pedantic -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -c -g -Iinc -Wall -pedantic -o obj/Wektor.o src/Wektor.cpp
src/Wektor.cpp: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Wektor&)’:
src/Wektor.cpp:11:12: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘float’)
   std::cin >> Wek[1] >> Wek[2] >> Wek[3];
            ^
src/Wektor.cpp:11:12: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from inc/Wektor.hh:5,
                 from src/Wektor.cpp:1:
```

Why does it say that something is wrong with >> with float as second operator? I guess [] itself is working somehow, becase it interpretes it as a float type but why it cannot interact with >> ? I'm new to this so if it is something simple and obvious sorry but I can't find it.
I'm aware it might be happening due to getting/not getting references but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your operator returns by value:

```
float operator[] (int i);
```

When you pass the result of this directly to `operator>>`, you are passing a temporary, and this operator needs an *lvalue reference*, something it is allowed to modify. Technically speaking, you cannot bind an *rvalue reference* (the temporary) to a non-const reference in standard C++.

So, change the operator to return a reference:

```
float& operator[] (int i);
```

It is common practice to provide a `const` overload, returning a `const` reference:

```
const float& operator[] (int i) const;
```

Comment: Your const overload has the wrong return type. Also, you normally return by value for small enough builtin types instead of using a constant reference.

Comment: @Deduplicator Oops, cut and paste fail. I'll keep the reference though. Returning by value is not the same.

Comment: Matter of style and efficiency if not inlined, which is the reason I avoid the reference in that case (Unless I write a template and it's extra work). I'm sure one could start a good flame there...

Comment: @Deduplicator It is not a matter of style. The semantics are totally different. I would find it confusing to change the return type like that based on the constness of the method.

Comment: Semantics = How it can be used. Far as i see, the only additional valid use is taking the address. Depends on what you see const ref is for, which i see as: Avoiding copy for efficiency / correctness.

Comment: OK thanks, but how do I return it then? I get an error "error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘float&’ from expression of type ‘const float’
"
Also, this operator will of course return a reference to element that can be modified. Should I overload another for 'return value' usage then?
EDIT: Ckecking it out after edit :)

Comment: @Deduplicator not taking the address. Holding a reference to the element. Changing the semantics of a method for some micro-optimization seems wrong to me.

Comment: @user3142453 add the second overload, and if you still have an error, post the code that produced the error.

Comment: It's all ok :)
But, if you would be so kind to help one more time, when index [] overload is working, how do I use it in a method? For example in method adding two vectors (this and passed v2) I try to type v2[1]+=this[1] and it says this[1] is of vestor type instead of float type ([] index should return float and it is in v2[1] case).

Comment: @user3142453 Probably something like `v2[2] += operator[](1);`, but usually (this is just a preference or a common convention, not a rule) you don't modify the argument, but you modify this, so `operator[](1) += v2[1];`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working but I guess I'll just overload them outside class instead so it will be easier to read. Thanks again, you saved my day (or, uhm, night) in this thread even if it was simple and dumb mistake :)